# MYSQL Change multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I got this table :

```
APPLICATION     TEST    DESCRIPTION     FICHIERCONF     FICHIERXML  FICHIERPROXY    PORTAIL     PERIODEMAINTENANCE  NOMDNS  TPSWARN     TPSCRIT     TYPEMAJ     TYPERAPPORT     CONTREMESURE    TPSCONTREMESURE     AUTH_URL    APP_URL_ENC
cerbere     Application-Ping    test    cete-config-cerbere     cerbere.xml     config-no-proxy.xml     0       cerbere.application.i2  0   0   1   Nagios  1   30  NULL    NULL
cerbere     Application-Ping2   test    cete-config-cerbere     cerbere.xml     config-no-proxy.xml     0       cerbere.application.i2  0   0   1   Nagios  1   30  NULL    NULL
```

For 1 single row I want to change 'cerbere' each time i see it by another text, in ALL columns.

For exemple i say : change 'cerbere' in the first row by 'lidia'. I want my application field to be changed by 'lidia', fichierconf field changed by 'cete-config-lidia', fichierxml by lidia.xml, nomdns by 'lidia.application.i2'.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the update table syntax.

```
update 
TABLE_NAME 
set 
FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, 'find this string', 'replace found string with this string')
, ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME = REPLACE(ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME, 'foo', 'bar')
, AND_ANOTHER_ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME = REPLACE(...)
... /*as much columns as you like*/
;
```

You could do this for each column although there might be still a better solution this quick and dirty hack should get you started.

Comment: Thx for the REPLACE thing, but how can i do without knowing the FiledName but for all fields?

Comment: I don't understand. So you want to be able to pick an arbitrary table and then examine all the columns and check for the occurence of some string? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: With your syntax, i need to do like 10 times this query for each column. As i want to do this for all columns of my table, is there  a way to do all of them in one request?

Comment: update TABLE_NAME tn set tn.* = replace(tn.*, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’); I am not certain however this will work

Comment: @JonathanCummins The query in your comment above doesn't work. You have to specify each column.